# javascript: my code is supposed to begin a countdown from 60 but the number values aren't appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is supposed to begin a countdown from 60 but the number values aren't appearing.
The timer begins but is only showing undefined/NaN.
 Ive ran through the code a few times and haven't found the issue.
 What did I do wrong? Thanks.
 The remaining is just to take up room for the required amount of text/code ratio.

```js
   //If we click on the start/reset button
    document.getElementById("startreset").onclick = function () {

      //If we are playing
      if (playing == true) {

        location.reload(); //reload page

      } else { //If we are not playing

        //change mode to playing
        playing = true;

        //set score to 0
        score = 0;
        document.getElementById("scorevalue").innerHTML = score;

        //show countdown box
        show("timeremaining")
        document.getElementById("timeremainingvalue").innerHTML = timeremaining;

        //change button to reset
        document.getElementById("startreset").innerHTML = " Reset";

        //start countdown
        startCountdown();

        //generate new Q&A
        generateQA();
      }

    };

    //reload page

    //reduce time by one second in loop
    //time left?
    //Yes->continue
    //No->game over

    //generate new Q&A

    //If we click on answer box
    //If we are playing
    //correct?
    //yes
    //increase score by one
    //show correct box
    //generate new Q&A
    //no
    //show try again box


    //functions

    //start counter
    function startCountdown() {
      action = setInterval(function () {
        timeremaining -= 1;

        document.getElementById("timeremainingvalue").innerHTML = timeremaining;
        if (timeremaining == 0) { //game over
          clearInterval(action);
          stopCountdown();
          show("gameOver");
          document.getElementById("gameOver").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "<p>Game Over.</p><p>You scored: " + score + ".</p>";
          hide("timeremaining");
          hide("correct");
          hide("wrong");
          playing = false;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    //stop counter
    function stopCountdown() {
      clearInterval(action);
    }

    //hide an element
    function hide(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }

    //show an element
    function show(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }

    //generate Q and multiple A
    function generateQA() {

    }
```

```css
/* no css */
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="score">
    score:
    <span id="scorevalue">0</span>
  </div>
  <div id="correct">
      correct
  </div>
  <div id="wrong">
      try again
  </div>
  <div id="question">
  </div>
  <div id="instruction">
    Click on the correct answer.
  </div>
  <div id="choices">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="startreset">
    Start Game
  </div>
  <div id="timeremaining">
    Time Remaining <span id="timeremainingvalue">60</span> sec
  </div>
  <div id="gameOver">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not possible to give a good answer if you don't reduce things and show the HTML too.

Comment: You haven't set `timeremaining` as a global variable, so it can't decrease its number, etc.

Comment: wasnt setting my ''' var timeremaining;''' setting it as a global function?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to use some global window variables to pass data around. Here is a [fiddle](http://fiddle%20with%20your%20updated%20code)with your updated code.Here is the updated html and javascript:

```js
//If we click on the start/reset button
window.timerIsPlaying = false;
window.timeRemaining = 60;
document.getElementById('startreset').onclick = function() {
 //If we are playing
 if (window.timerIsPlaying == true) {
  location.reload(); //reload page
 } else {
  //If we are not playing

  //change mode to playing
  window.timerIsPlaying = true;

  //set score to 0
  score = 0;
  document.getElementById('scorevalue').innerHTML = score;

  //show countdown box
  show('timeremaining');
  document.getElementById('timeremainingvalue').innerText = window.timeRemaining;

  //change button to reset
  document.getElementById('startreset').innerHTML = ' Reset';

  //start countdown
  startCountdown();

  //generate new Q&A
  generateQA();
 }
};

//reload page

//reduce time by one second in loop
//time left?
//Yes->continue
//No->game over

//generate new Q&A

//If we click on answer box
//If we are playing
//correct?
//yes
//increase score by one
//show correct box
//generate new Q&A
//no
//show try again box

//functions

//start counter
function startCountdown() {
 action = setInterval(function() {
  window.timeRemaining -= 1;

  document.getElementById('timeremainingvalue').innerHTML = window.timeRemaining;
  if (timeremaining == 0) {
   //game over
   clearInterval(action);
   stopCountdown();
   show('gameOver');
   document.getElementById('gameOver').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('gameOver').innerHTML = '<p>Game Over.</p><p>You scored: ' + score + '.</p>';
   hide('timeremaining');
   hide('correct');
   hide('wrong');
   playing = false;
  }
 }, 1000);
}

//stop counter
function stopCountdown() {
 clearInterval(action);
}

//hide an element
function hide(id) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}

//show an element
function show(id) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

//generate Q and multiple A
function generateQA() {}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="score">
    score:
    <span id="scorevalue">0</span>
  </div>
  <div id="correct">
    correct
  </div>
  <div id="wrong">
    try again
  </div>
  <div id="question"></div>
  <div id="instruction">
    Click on the correct answer.
  </div>
  <div id="choices">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="startreset">
    Start Game
  </div>
  <div id="timeremaining">
    Time Remaining <span id="timeremainingvalue">60</span> sec
  </div>
  <div id="gameOver"></div>
</div>
```

It looks like in code provided and I believe this is what Phillip was referring to in his comment , was the timeremaining remaining variable not being accessible. I put it on the window object and and updating it there now. I hope this help.